# como obtener un token en oauth 2, con swift 3 ios, este codigo esta con la api de twitter

Tags: ios, swift3

```
 var oauthswift: OAuth2Swift?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey:    "VTkUsZX4Yqzlzlu6MBLdcIJoP",
        consumerSecret: "1TdkkuboBIJjEOZsOk7NIiFlQbLtfAf1Lbvgqp72qLfGLXDACf",
        authorizeUrl:    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl:  "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
        responseType: "code"

    )

    let handle = oauthswift?.authorize(
withCallbackURL: URL(string: "TestOauth://testoauth/twitter")!,
        scope: "full", state:"state",
        success: { credential, response, parameters in
            print(credential.oauthToken)
            print(credential.oauthTokenSecret)
            print(parameters["user_id"])
//
    },
        failure: { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    )
}
}
```

> no me regresa ningún token, me manda un error que no fue solicitado el token, gracias

Comment: ¿Has leído la documentación de Twitter?

Comment: revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes: Lean bien la documentación oficial de cualquier API, librería, ahí se encuentra todo lo necesario.

1. En la documentación oficial de Twitter dice bien claro lo siguiente:

> Para generar el token se necesita crear la cadena en Base 64 de
>   consumerKey + consumerSecret, formateado de la siguiente manera consumerKey:consumerSecret.

Entonces, tenemos:

```
consumerKey:    "VTkUsZX4Yqzlzlu6MBLdcIJoP",
consumerSecret: "1TdkkuboBIJjEOZsOk7NIiFlQbLtfAf1Lbvgqp72qLfGLXDACf",
```

Esto se transforma bajo el formato de `consumerKey:consumerSecret`

```
var preparandoCadena = "VTkUsZX4Yqzlzlu6MBLdcIJoP:1TdkkuboBIJjEOZsOk7NIiFlQbLtfAf1Lbvgqp72qLfGLXDACf";
```

Aplicas algun método de swift para genera la Base 64 de la variable anterior.

Y como resultado tienes:

```
VlRrVXpTWDRZcXpsemx1Nk1CTGRjSUpvUDoxVGRra3Vib0JJSmpFT1pzT2s3TklpRmxRYkx0ZkFmMUxidmdcxDI3cUxmR0xYREFDZg==
```

Ahora bien, en los headers necesitas pasar:

```
key: Authorization
value: Basic VlRrVXpTWDRZcXpsemx1Nk1CTGRjSUpvUDoxVGRra3Vib0JJSmpFT1pzT2s3TklpRmxRYkx0ZkFmMUxidmdcxDI3cUxmR0xYREFDZg==
```

En el body del request:

```
key: grant_type
value: client_credentials
```

Usando Postman hago la petición y aquí te presento a tu token:

```
{
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "access_token": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA160QAAAAAAuxypuPwkbAfAqtdE2Px7ps%2By3%2FM%3DPKX1Cs6lhrm8Pk7HZH7YkeEH0V6vEPeHWrnraIuaDBziwIIWqR"
}
```

Resetea una nueva llave por motivos de seguridad. Si este ejemplo no te funciona es porque le he cambiado el contenido de llaves.

Finalmente para utilizar alguna función de la API de twitter, en la  documentación dice que debemos agregar el Bearer token.

```
key: Authorization
value: Bearer AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA160QAAAAAAuxypuPwkbAfAqtdE2Px7ps%2By3%2FM%3DPKX1Cs6lhrm8Pk7HZH7YkeEH0V6vEPeHWrnraIuaDBziwIIWqR
```

Nótese que hay un espacio entre Bearer y {token}

PD: Hace un tiempo también jugué con la API Twittera dando como resultado un motor que alimenta mi biblioteca de bookmarks que saco de twitter: http://fredyfx.com/resources

**Mediante OAUTH2 en SWIFT:**

Resulta que sólo se tenía que modificar la clase `OAuth2CodeGrant` para añadir en el client_secret que no se estaba pasando durante el intercambio de código para el token:

```
open func accessTokenRequest(with code: String, params: OAuth2StringDict? = nil) throws -> OAuth2AuthRequest {
    guard let clientId = clientConfig.clientId, !clientId.isEmpty else {
        throw OAuth2Error.noClientId
    }
    guard let redirect = context.redirectURL else {
        throw OAuth2Error.noRedirectURL
    }

    guard let clientSecret = clientConfig.clientSecret else {
        throw OAuth2Error.noClientSecret
    }

    let req = OAuth2AuthRequest(url: (clientConfig.tokenURL ?? clientConfig.authorizeURL), method: .GET)

    req.params["code"] = code
    req.params["grant_type"] = type(of: self).grantType
    req.params["redirect_uri"] = redirect
    req.params["client_id"] = clientId
    req.params["client_secret"] = clientSecret

    return req
}
```

Referencia de esto último: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41247962/3613462